# Android app automation using UIAutomator2 tool

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I am working on automation of an app and there is as per requirement for android device need to be automated using `UiAutomator2`. I have seen in some of the tutorials that is just an locator technique. I have not worked on this tool anytime. I have worked on `Appium` earlier. It will be helpful if anyone can share the sample script.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you listed all your requirements:

The only difference you will notice is adding this capability to your driver instance:

```
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
```

and that your tests will be running faster. UiAutomator2 is not a locator technique. It's different framework for automating Android apps.

If you actually need to use new kind of locator you probably meant UiSelector.

Example code in java:

```
driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().resourceId(\"appPackage:id/LoginButton\")");
```

More UiSelector strategies can be found here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiSelector